# Find contact in distribution lists and subgroups

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I often have to find if a person recieved an email from an automatic tool. The problem is, the tool sends emails to specific distribution lists which contain even more distribution lists. Is there a fast way to find if a specific user is inside any of these distribution lists?

I've been trying to do this by going to "Find a contact" and looking at every distribution list manually, but it takes ages and my head starts to hurt after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is not much distribution lists within the specific distribution list, you may consider to type the specific distribution list in the To: field, click the + to expand each distribution list and then copy all the contacts in the To: field to a text editor, such as a .tet file. Then press Ctrl + F and search for the the specific person.

If you are using Skype for Business, you may also consider to open the people's contact card and then view the 'Membership' of the people. It will list all the distribution lists the people is in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I found the same solution after I asked the question. It would be cool if I could resize `To:` field because it is about 3 lines high, but it is still much less work than going through each distribution list.